# Laravel phpunit drops database tables

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I'm trying to test my app using phpunit with laravel but each time I run

unit test

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```

All tables in my database drop so I have to migrate each time I run a test

Have you encountered with similar issue  & how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate connection for tests. Add this connection to `config/database.php` config file:

```
'connections' => [

    'testing' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Comment: I will try it, but can I use my default database  since I'm not in production environment?

Comment: I don't recommend using the default database for testing.

Comment: @user3763103 why do you want to do that? I agree with Camilo, you should use in-memory database for testing.

Comment: Because I'm building the app in a local environment once I done I will move it to the server therefor I thought that I don't need two databases. Anyway it worked Thank you  very much.